# Destructor in C#

Tags: c#

Is there any difference between a class with destructor and with out destructor.

e.g

```
class WithOut {    }
class With
{
    ~With(){}
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes.  From the documentation for [Destructors](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/66x5fx1b.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396):

> Empty destructors should not be used. When a class contains a destructor, an entry is created in the Finalize queue. When the destructor is called, the garbage collector is invoked to process the queue. If the destructor is empty, this just causes a needless loss of performance.